# Is this incredibly intelligent or absolutely useless "where (table.field = NULL or null is null)"?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, null

I have found that snippet in a query many times, for almost every table in the FROM. I can't find any sense to it. Can anyone help, please? My gut tells me it's useless, but maybe it's something so clever that's way over my head. Example:

```
Select a.field1, b.field2, c.field3
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on (a.field1 = b.id)
left join table 3 c on (b.field2 = c.id)
where a.field 3 = "VALUE"
and ( a.field1 = NULL or NULL IS NULL)
and ( b.field2 = NULL or NULL IS NULL)
```

Comment: Nothing can `=` `NULL`.  Period.  Not even another `NULL`.  The logic is broken, as it will always be true via the `OR NULL IS NULL`. It's essentially pointless to even add to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The code is garbage: `a.field1 = NULL or NULL IS NULL` is identical to `true`

Comment: My best guess that these are computer-generated queries and those NULLs are used as benign space holders for real variables.  Kinda like `1=1`.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines that maybe this was a way to force indexes or something.

Comment: Is the query actually hard-coded like this or is this a dynamically generated query?  If I saw something like this, I would guess that there was a piece of code that had three parameters passed to it and this was a way of applying optional filters (i.e. if the value for `field1` is NULL then ignore otherwise filter).  If the code was dynamically generating a query of the form `(a.field1 = <<value of parameter 1>> or <<value of parameter1>> IS NULL)`, that would at least make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL IS NULL` is always true, so combining it with any other condition with an `or` operator will also result in true, making the last two conditions useless. This query could be rewritten without them:

```
Select a.field1, b.field2, c.field3
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on (a.field1 = b.id)
left join table 3 c on (b.field2 = c.id)
where a.field 3 = "VALUE"
```

Comment: I was thinking along the lines that maybe this was a way to force indexes or something.

Comment: @user2953027 I'd like to see the execution plans of both queries, but any half-decent optimizer will just write out any condition based on literals.

Comment: Both are the same, so I'm guessing Oracle is half-decent. Anyway, i'll just toss it all and start over. Thanks, Mureinik!